# How to add text with specific color to a vertical header item in a qtablewidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a qtablewidget. I need to put a single *red-colored* exclamation mark in *some* of the vertical header items after actual header text. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QTableWidgetItem` seems to not support rich texts, so you can't have a multi-colored text set to it. You can only set color of its whole text.

```
ui->tbl->verticalHeaderItem(1)->setText("Hello");
ui->tbl->verticalHeaderItem(1)->setTextColor(Qt::red);
```

[image]

Comment: Oh some limitation there. But above suggestion is sufficient for my work. Thanks!